# Zune Software crash when connecting Windows Phone 7 after regedit changes

Tags: usb, sync, connection, windows-phone, zune-software

When I connect my LG Optimus 7 to my PC with the Zune software, it show me this error:

[image]
[image]

In My PC, I **cannot see** my device.
The only change that I remember in registry editor (with **MFC App**) are USB *connection mode*:

- **USB Switching option in Menu Engineer -> Port Setting**.
  Like QC COMPOSITE, Microsoft COMPOSITE, etc...

I tried all combinations, but nothing... Device won't show in PC!

Zune software show my phone for a moment and crash after this error!

How to fix this issue?
Is there a way to reset USB connection mode?

I need to deploy apps from Visual Studio to phone (and update my phone) and my Zune won't work!!

EDIT: Added english version of error.

Comment: Can has English? Half the people here can't even write English, let alone read Spanish.

Comment: @Hello71 See edit. Added english version of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved upgrading to mango beta. First of that i reset my phone and it works.